# Determining if a specific form field has a required error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive that wraps a text input field. One of the things I plan to embed in this directive is the validation behavior when it is required, but I'm stuck on one point. You are supposed to be able to refer to the validation errors for an input field using myForm.myField.$error or myForm[myField].$error. However, because my input is created by my directive, it shows up as myForm["{{myDirectiveName"].$error. This is unacceptable because I will have many such fields and I need to distinguish between them.

[Plunkr that illustrates this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBnNUUULhpvRfAYnmtAH?p=preview).

The key line that causes problems is this:

```
console.log( !! form["{{htTextField}}"].$error.required);
```

What I expect to be able to write is:

```
console.log( !! form[attrs.htTextField].$error.required);
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by implementing my own required directive, borrowed from angular's, and customized to modify my own scope variables. Perhaps what I observed in my question is a bug, but I'm not expert enough to fix it in angular's code.